# Facing linking trouble with mkl in linux Intel compiler (icc)

Tags: dynamic-linking, icc, intel-mkl

here is the command line in linux:

```
icc test.c -o test.o -L/opt/intel/current/mkl/intel64 -I/opt/intel/current/mkl/include -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_scalapack_ilp64
```

after running this command: I got a long line of *undefined reference errors*. I have also tried in eclipse but could not resolve the linking problem there too. I would be happy if anyone just help me to run a small code like this:

```
//test.c- a sample code from user guide
#include "mkl.h"
#define N 5
void main()
{
int n, inca = 1, incb = 1, i;
typedef struct{ double re; double im; } complex16;
complex16 a[N], b[N], c;
void zdotc();
n = N;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
a[i].re = (double)i; a[i].im = (double)i * 2.0;
b[i].re = (double)(n - i); b[i].im = (double)i * 2.0;
}
zdotc( &c, &n, a, &inca, b, &incb );
printf( "The complex dot product is: ( %6.2f, %6.2f) ", c.re, c.im );
}
```

my server

```
> MKLROOT: /opt/intel/current/mkl/
>           library: $MKLROOT/lib/intel64/
>           include:$MKLROOT/include
```

ICC 64bit is installed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: At last I have solved the problem: I did not export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=....:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Thats why it could not find the those symbols. I have linked with eclipse+mkl in linux 64 bit. If anyone wants to know, I can give graphical instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get right linkline for Intel MKL is using [MKL Linkline Advisor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor/). Even with right LD_LIBRARY_PATH compiler options and set of libraries you link doesn't look right. Should be

```
-DMKL_ILP64 -I$(MKLROOT)/include -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -openmp -lpthread -lm
```